# How to pass the final resolve variable in a promise chain with module exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, google-cloud-functions

I have three chained promises above this last bit of code here: getChannel, getPlaylist, and getVideoViews.

```
module.exports = {
 runScript: function(channelID, accessToken, callback) {
  YoutubeAPI.authenticate({
    type: "oauth",
    token: accessToken
  });


  getChannel(channelID)
  .then(getPlaylist)
  .then(getVideoViews)
  .then(function(views){
    callback(views);
  })
 }
}
```

I have another file, user.js which is dependant on the resolve of getVideoViews (which is an array of video view counts). The code in user.js is the following:

```
      youtuber1.runScript(channelID, accessToken, function(error, response, views){
        console.log(views);
      });
```

The console log, however, results in undefined. Chaining the promises made it really easy for me to execute these functions one after the other, but I'm quite lost on now how to pass the resolve of the last function back to my user.js.

I'm a bit of a beginner with promises and callbacks and would love some help!

Comment: This has little to do with promises or callbacks, it's simply knowing how to call a function :p you call the callback using `callback(views);` ... vs the callback `function(error, response, views)` .... the callback expects views to be the third argument, you are passing it as the first argument - change `function(error, response, views){` to `function(views){` or `callback(views);` to `callback(null, null, views);`

Comment: Are you sure you want to mix Promises and Callbacks? You can just return the promise chain and call in `then()` on it in your other file.

Comment: aww shucks @JaromandaX, thank you! Works 100% now. Sometimes I wish I had someone like right next to me to just tell me when I'm doing something stupid and that the fix is a 2 second fix, instead of spending too much time trying to figure something silly out!

Comment: I second @Mark_M.  You're mixing callbacks with promises here.  While it may "work", it's not necessarily a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Your callback function is `function(error, response, views) { ... }`, but when you use it in `runScript` you use `callback(views)`, so the parameters aren't matching.  Consider doing something like this, with an error and response parameter (you can do however many parameters you need).

```
module.exports = {
 runScript: function(channelID, accessToken, callback) {
  YoutubeAPI.authenticate({
    type: "oauth",
    token: accessToken
  });


  getChannel(channelID)
  .then(getPlaylist)
  .then(getVideoViews)
  .then(function(views){
    callback(null, views);
  })
 }
}
```

**user.js**

```
youtuber1.runScript(channelID, accessToken, function(error, response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on Mark_M's answer, you can also `await` promises.

```
module.exports = {
    runScript: async function(channelID, accessToken) {
        YoutubeAPI.authenticate({
            type: "oauth",
            token: accessToken
        });
        var channel = await getChannel(channelID)
        var playlist = await getPlaylist(channel)
        var views = await getVideoViews(playlist)
        return views
    }
}

var views = await youtuber1.runScript(channelID, accessToken)
```

just be aware that you can only await things in an async function. That is functions declared with the async keyword. If you are outside of any function, you can do it with an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned it in a comment, but it's probably worth a short example just in case the comment isn't clear.

Since you already have a nice promise to work with, you can just return it without dealing with callbacks:

```
module.exports = {
 runScript: function(channelID, accessToken, callback) {
  YoutubeAPI.authenticate({
    type: "oauth",
    token: accessToken
  });
  // return that promise
  return getChannel(channelID)
  .then(getPlaylist)
  .then(getVideoViews)
 }
}
```

Then in your other file, things are and easier and cleaner too:

```
youtuber1.runScript(channelID, accessToken)
.then(function(views){
   // your views are ready here
})
.catch(function(err){
   // deal with errors here
 }
```

Comment: amazing. I did not know that was possible. That makes much more sense and is a lot cleaner too. thank you, Mark!

Comment: I just tried this out and when I ran it I got this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. It is referring to your last code in my "other file".
It looks like it is trying to run .then(function(views) before runScript has ran. I only guess that because the console.log I put where you put "your views are ready here", gets called first and then results in that error.

Comment: Hmm, that suggests that getChannel isn't returning anything. Are you sure the `runScript()` is actually working and `getChannel` is returning something?

Comment: I believe so. Because when I change my callback to reflect the suggestions others made, I am able to console log "views" in the other code and it returns the correct values. This should be working, though? I want it to work!